# Ransack - Ignore dashes in search field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using Ransack for search filtering in my app and I have a request from the client. They have the ability to search `Account` via `Account_number`. An account_number looks like this in our database `123456` but to the users the account number looks like this `123-456`. So when they search for the account number and add the dash the account is not found.

Is there a way to ignore `Dashes` in the search? Like, If a user puts a dash in the search, can I configure ransack to ignore that character?

Comment: can you not just remove the dash before passing it to ransack, e.g `account_number.delete('-')`?

Comment: You could configure the Front-End to strip dashes before submitting the form, or you could configure the Back-End to strip dashes from the parameter. Either way, this is a simple 1-liner, and not specific to ransack configuration.